# trac with multiple svn repos?

Tags: svn, trac

is there a way to configure trac to use more than one svn repo in trac.ini?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That functionality was added in version 0.12
http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/0.12/TracRepositoryAdmin

Comment: when is it available for download?